# Unknown lifecycle phase "dist"

Tags: maven, cygwin

I am building [apache hive](http://hive.apache.org/) from source on windows. Doing so asks me to executes the following command :

```
mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist
```

Trouble is, if I try to execute the following command without cygwin, I get this error :

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "dist". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>
:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, i
nitialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-
test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes,
 test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy,
 pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
```

However, if I launch the same command from cygwin, the compilation works perfectly.
Just to be sure, I checked there wasn't any version differences between the maven used with and without cygwin :

- `mvn -version` without cygwin

  ```
  Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:22+0200)
  Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.1.1
  Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java home: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
  Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
  OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
  ```
- `mvn -version` with cygwin

  ```
      Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:22+0200)
      Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.1.1
      Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
      Java home: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
      Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
      OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
  ```

As you can see, they're the same.

Is this due to hive, or are there any differences between windows-native maven and cygwin maven ?

Comment: It should not be linked to hive, as it is base parsing of the command. I would suspect strange characters (hyphen or something else) to have some side effects. Just tried the same command in the exact same environment as you (OS, Maven, Java identical), and it works fine.

Comment: Just try it that way: `mvn clean install -P hadoop-2,dist` this should work if not  please file in an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG

Comment: @Tome any ideas on these strange characters ? I have the src located on C:\hive, so I guess it doesn't come from the folder name.

Comment: @khmarbaise just tried, doesn't change anything.

Comment: I meant strange characters on the command you launch itself. Like when you copy paste text and there's an hyphen instead of a 'minus'. Here, the error you have is just like if there was no comma at all before 'dist'. Anyway, -Phadoop-2 -Pdist should work equally.

Comment: @Tome separating both properties makes the compilation work. However, I retried the previous command (typed everything just to be sure) and I didn't find strange characters.

Comment: I can only reproduce the thing if i type `mvn clean install -P hadoop-2, dist` (space before dist). Otherwise it works.